# Memcpy with floats in C++

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am having a problem with what would appear to be extremely simple code, yet it dosent do at all what I'd expect it to:

Code:

```
char b[sizeof(float)];
float a = 1.5f;
memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(float));
printf("%f\n", b[0]);
```

Output:

```
62827075002794546937726511559700164562271693617156259118887055013962964939146547
22493354730179062365918845182857228200743453702107162763566167344423902681816648
14169764096333089859051972349071751428406066879715295195780847944297207011246001
33742258486014791122944.000000
```

Yet it works when I do this:

```
char b[sizeof(int)];
int a = 3;
memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(int));
printf("%i\n", b[0]);
```

Output:

```
3
```

Why does this happen? Is it because of endianness or something?

Comment: You do notice that you are splitting the original `float` into bytes and then try to output only the first byte as `float`?

Comment: @Nabla Shouldnt it automatically know that floats are 4 bytes long and print 4 bytes of data starting at the address passed to the printf, because ints are 4 bytes long as well and they dont seem to be breaking.

Comment: No, how should it know? `int` only works because for small `int` the first byte equals its value, although even that might be implementation- and/or machine-dependent

Comment: b[0] evaluates to the first byte of the float, and when you call printf like that, it pushes ONLY that byte onto the stack as the argument. printf will then read that byte plus some random data off the stack to get the float you are telling it to print.

Comment: Also, if you assigned a value larger than 255 in the integer example, I think you'd see something different in the output there as well.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor: larger than 127, and you'll see something different (likely)

Comment: I guess the only way to print that data as a float is to copy it back on to another float variable then output that. It just seems weird that the float and char data is exactly the same yet printf knows when its a float to use more than 1 byte from it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh right, signed.

Comment: @lemondrop: Not the only way. You could use `printf("%f\n", *(float*)b)`

Comment: @mebob - for the call to `printf` the value of `b[0]` gets promoted to `int`. Same result: nonsense displayed.

Comment: Well thanks for the help everyone, this makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour. The expression `b[0]` is a `char` (promoted to `int`), and the format specifier `%f` expects a `double`.

(There could be any number of explanations for the output you see. The most urgent one that comes to mind is that a `double` is wider than an `int` on your platform and garbage memory is read. If you want a slightly more predictable experiment, try passing `static_cast<uint64_t>(b[0])` as the argument.)